# How to collect payment with default payment method in stripe subscription?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, subscription

I am trying to subscribe the customer with multiple subscription having different intervals

first of all,
I am creating a subscription, then using payment_intent in subscription object, I am rendering the payment_elements and asking users for the card details and confirmating payment.

now I want a user to subscribe to the other plans also without confirming or entering the payment details

***FYI - The user knows at this time that the payment_methods and card details are being used for total how much money***

I have created the other subscription using below code

```
let subs = {
    "customer": "cus_NWCqvdBhiQRQ2a",
    "items": [
        {
            "price_data": {
                "currency": "usd",
                "product": "prod_N8tG4peHRPUrsn",
                "recurring": { "interval": "month" },
                "unit_amount_decimal": "2150"
            },
            "quantity": 2
        }],
    "metadata": {
       
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that the invoice is failed and the subscription status is incomplete.
How can I collect payment from the default attached payment method ?

Answer (score 2):

For this to work, you need to:

1. Make sure the Customer has a default PaymentMethod set. If not, update the [`invoice_settings.default_payment_method`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method) property of the Customer object.
2. Create the second Subscription with [`payment_behavior: allow_incomplete`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-payment_behavior)
3. Check the subscription status. If it's `active` then great. If it's `incomplete`, it means the bank requested 3DS flow. In this case you need to ask the user to come back to your website/app and confirm the PaymentIntent of the first Invoice with [`confirmCardPayment`](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment#stripe_confirm_card_payment-attached) to start the 3DS flow.

Comment: I am updating the ```invoice_settings.default_payment_method``` in customer object before creating subscription, as you said I am also setting ```payment_behavior: allow_incomplete``` but still getting the  ```incomplete``` status

Comment: What's the status of the PaymentIntent? I'm guessing it's `requires_action`. So you need to follow the step 3 I outlined above.